# Azure DevOps Test plans for basic User?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-functions, test-plan

According to the Billing page of my Azure DevOps I am currently using the Basic account because I am giving the possibility to start a free trial of Basic + Test Plans

[image]

But Somehow I am able to create Test Plans and run tests, see the report etc. Is this usual that Basic users can access this section? If yes why would we need to pay for Basic+Test Plans variation?

[image]

Comment: are you having MSDN license?

Comment: In https://my.visualstudio.com/Subscriptions there is no Subscription

Comment: See Prerequisites here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/test/create-a-test-plan?view=azure-devops#prerequisites. If you area member of the Project Administrators group or have Manage Test Plans and Manage Test Suites permissions and you have Basic + Test Plans, you can create test plans.

Comment: Hi, do you still need help on this issue? Or you have got the answer?

Comment: Hi, I had to finally ask MS for this issue. Their answer was Yes, Basic users can access this section but users with Basic + Test Plans access level can use more features like create and manage test plans and test suits, prepare user acceptance testing etc. See the link for more Information: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/test/manual-test-permissions?view=azure-devops

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basic Users can execute UnitTest using Test Plans service of Azure DevOps for free but for certain cases there is the Basic+Test Plans account needed. What is included in the Basic account and what has to be additionally purchased is listed [HERE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/test/manual-test-permissions?view=azure-devops#license-requirements)